# lambda function and sets

Tags: function, lambda, set

I need to remove all elements from set that satisfy the lambda function, is there a way to make it continue when the fisrt part of the statement returns error?

```
f = lambda x : x < "t" or x % 2 == 0

s = {"a", 2, "u",  4, 3}


def sort(fun, s):
    l = []
    for element in s:
        try:
            if (fun(element)) == True:
                l.append(element)
        except:
            pass


    for element in l:
        s.remove(element)
```

my code returns:

```
s = {2, 3, 4, 'u'}
```

but I need it to return:

```
s = { 3, 'u'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adjust a lambda function to check the type of the element.

Also, to remove values from set use set-comprehension:

```py
f = lambda x: (isinstance(x, str) and x < "t") or (
    isinstance(x, int) and x % 2 == 0
)

s = {"a", 2, "u", 4, 3}


s = {v for v in s if not f(v)}
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
{'u', 3}
```